# Find average of each ClosedRange in array of ClosedRanges

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of `ClosedRange` `Double`s as follows:

```
var ranges = [ClosedRange<Double>]()
```

Is there a swifty way to retrieve the average of each `ClosedRange` without having to iterate over each element in the array, and then each number in each `ClosedRange`?

For example, if the array is:

```
[ClosedRange(1...3), ClosedRange(4...5)]
```

I would like to retrieve: `2, 4.5`

Comment: What do you mean by "each number in the closed range"? You just need the upper and lower bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to coerce  lower and upper bounds to Double, sum them and then divide by two:

```
let ranges = [1...3, 4...5]
let avgs = ranges.map {
    (Double($0.lowerBound) + Double($0.upperBound)) / 2
}
print(avgs)  // "[2.0, 4.5]\n"
```

If your range's bounds are already Doubles:

```
let ranges = [1.0...3.0, 4.0...5.0]
let avgs = ranges.map {
    ($0.lowerBound + $0.upperBound) / 2
}
print(avgs)  // "[2.0, 4.5]\n"
```